# Run docker inside docker as non root user

Tags: linux, docker

How can I run docker commands inside a docker container when the user is not root?

The reason behind this (running as non root) is that the (first) container creates some files on a mounted volume. If the user in the container is root then these files' owner is also root. If I run the container with the same user as on the host system then these files have the correct user and group.

```
docker run --rm -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu /bin/bash

// inside container:
// assume docker binary is available
docker pull alpine
```

This will not work when run as a non root user giving following error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=alpine&tag=latest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Comment: This is subject to ordinary Unix permissions on the mounted file.  You may need to `docker run --add-group` with the group ID that owns the socket.  Do remember that access to the Docker socket comes with the ability to very easily root the entire host; your non-root user isn't giving up a lot of power if it has access to the host's `/var/run/docker.sock`.

Comment: Why not use `docker:dind-rootless`?

Comment: @DavidMaze Do you have an example? I checked which group has permission for the socket file on the host machine and then used its group id for the `--group-add` parameter. However this did not change the error message. Btw, the main reason I want to run as the same user as on the host system is that the container created files in a mounted volume and I need to have access to these files. So I need the owner to not be root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker:

```
docker run -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) --group-add $(getent group docker | cut -d ':' -f 3) --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker docker --version
```

For Docker Compose set `group_add` under your service and set the env variable:

```
export DOCKER_GROUP_ID=$(getent group docker | cut -d ':' -f 3);
```

```
services:
  myservice:
    image: docker
    group_add:
      - ${DOCKER_GROUP_ID}
```